# Working with folders

Tags: asp.net

I have two folders inside my asp.net site.

The first one contains files for the express version of my application while the second contains the full version.

Now I want to be able to set anyone of the folders as the default application based on my selection at first load

Answer (score 0):

Create a flag field for the two folders. Like if I have the situation . I will assign the folder some unique id like 1 for Express and 2 for Full. From admin panel i will assign the user or application to display the app.

Like in my table i will create a field like DisplayVersion of type tinyint and will store 1 or 2 in it depending upon the scenario